# Neo4j : how to implement SKIP and LIMIT on a UNION cypher ? What are the alternatives?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create an activity feed across various relationships.

The only way I have managed to do it so far is using `UNION` to run 3 statements.  However, you can't `LIMIT` and `ORDER` across the results of all the unions – it appears to be a limitation of Neo at the moment.

Does anyone know how I could re write the below so I can order and limit the whole lot?

```
match (me:User {username:'bob'})-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(u:User)
return m as message, u as user, lower(type(r)) as activity, r.created_on as date  
order by date skip 0 limit 25

union match (me:User {username:'bob'})<-[r:Mentions]-(m:Message)-[:Owner]-(u:User) 
return m as message, u as user, lower(type(r)) as activity, r.created_on as date
order by date skip 0 limit 25

union match (me:User {username:'bob'})<-[r:Follows]-(u:User)
return NULL as message, u as user, lower(type(r)) as activity, r.created_on as date
order by date skip 0 limit 25
```

I got to this, which returns a single column with the data i need as nested properties, but I cant work out how to order the final collection.....

```
match (me:User {username:'bob'})-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(u:User)
with collect({activity:lower(type(r)), user:u, message:m, date:r.created_on}) as a1

optional match (me:User {username:'bob'})<-[r:Mentions]-(m:Message)-[:Owner]-(u:User) 
with collect({activity:lower(type(r)), user:u, message:m, date:r.created_on }) as a2, a1 

optional match (me:User {username:'bob'})<-[r:Follows]-(u:User) 
with collect({activity:lower(type(r)), user:u, date:r.created_on }) as  a3, a2, a1

with a3 + a2 +a1 as all
unwind all as activity
return activity
skip 0 limit 25
```

Any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

So now I have this....

```
MATCH (me:User { username:'bob' })--(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(u)
WITH me, collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:u, message:m, date:r.created_on }) AS a1
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[r:Mentions]-(m:Message)<-[:Owner]-(u)
WITH me, collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:u, message:m, date:r.created_on }) AS a2, a1
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[r:Follows]-(u)
WITH collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:u, date:r.created_on })+ a2 + a1 AS all
UNWIND all AS activity
WITH activity
WHERE  activity.type is not null
RETURN activity
ORDER BY activity.date
LIMIT 25;
```

Can anyone see any performance issues with this?

Im matching me--user at the start to make sure I only look for users I have some relationship with.  Then at the end I filter out the NUll matches from the OPTIONAL matches.  As i'm manually collecting a literal object, it gets an object with NULL entries if nothing was matched, so I just remove these at the end....

All this because you cant filter POST UNION!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to do "post-UNION processing" is not yet supported, but is promised "as soon as possible" (see [neo4j issue 2725](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725)). You may want to add comments to that issue if you would like this to happen soon.

Your attempted solution was close. This query should work better:

```
MATCH (me:User { username:'bob' })-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(u:User)
WITH me, collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:u, message:m, date:r.created_on }) AS a1
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[r:Mentions]-(m:Message)<-[:Owner]-(u:User)
WITH me, collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:u, message:m, date:r.created_on }) AS a2, a1
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[r:Follows]-(u:User)
WITH collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:u, date:r.created_on })+ a2 + a1 AS all
UNWIND all AS activity
RETURN activity
ORDER BY activity.date
LIMIT 25;
```

This query:

- `ORDERS BY` the date of the combined activities, so that the 25 earliest activities are returned. This was the main change needed to your query.
- Eliminates the unneeded `SKIP 0` clause.
- Passes `me` through the first 2 `WITH` clauses so that the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses don't have to re-find `me` again.

Comment: Ah, yes, the collect and unwind!  Don't know why I didn't think about that ;)

Comment: I'm thinking about what I said below about it slowing down as the number of users grows and I think that this might slow down even faster because you have three different `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses between `WITH`s as so I think it's going to scan the `User` label three times in this case

Comment: Great!  Looking at @BrianUnderwood's comments below, should I MATCH any relationship between `me` and the `user` first, and then optional match with the `Likes`, `Reply` and `Share` relationship, as there may be NO like reply or share link....    `MATCH (me:User { username:'bob' })--(u:User)       OPTIONAL MATCH (me:User { username:'bob' })-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(u)`

Comment: You can't use the `MATCH` clause to define a set of alternate paths that it can choose from.  You could use `WHERE (path) OR (path) OR (path)` but I think that might have the same performance problems and you would need to repeat the paths in `OPTIONAL MATCH`s anyway to define variables which you can return.

Comment: If you have one path that you know is always going to be connected for the users that you're looking for (like you want to limit your query by the `Follows` relationship) you can `MATCH` on that relationship first which will be much more performant because it just needs to traverse the `Follows` relationship which will narrow your results a lot.  But I can understand why that might not be a good solution

Comment: Yeah, good point, it is actually ignoring some of the activities doing that.   However, If I match just on the end user , `MATCH (me:User { username:'bob' }), (user:User)`  I get results that have NO relationship to `me`.   How can you have optional paths then?  So I want to match me and a user, but only if they are related by one or more of the paths in the example?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
MATCH (me:User {username:'bob'}), (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Owner]->(m1:Message)<-[message_type:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(user)
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[mentions:Mentions]-(m2:Message)-[:Owner]-(user) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[follows:Follows]-(user)
WITH *
WHERE message_type IS NOT NULL OR mentions IS NOT NULL OR follows IS NOT NULL
RETURN
  COALESCE(m1, m2) AS message,
  user,
  lower(COALESCE(type(message_type), type(mentions), type(follows))),
  COALESCE(message_type.date, mentions.date, follows.date) AS date
ORDER BY date
SKIP 0
LIMIT 25
```

The main disadvantage here (aside from all the COALESCEs ;) is that since there are only `OPTIONAL MATCH` paths from `me` to `user` that you'll end up matching `me` against every single user which means your query might grow more slow as you get more users.  That's why I put the `WHERE` in there after the `WITH`, because you need to filter out all of the cases where there is no path between the two users.

**EDIT:**

I just realized that this is a problematic solution.  If two or more of your `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses match then you'll only get one result.  You could do something like this:

```
MATCH (me:User {username:'bob'}), (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Owner]->(message:Message)<-[message_type:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(user)
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[mentions:Mentions]-(mention_message:Message)-[:Owner]-(user) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[follows:Follows]-(user)
WITH *
WHERE message_type IS NOT NULL OR mentions IS NOT NULL OR follows IS NOT NULL
RETURN
  message,
  mention_message
  user,
  type(message_type) AS message_type_type,
  type(mentions) AS mentions_type,
  type(follows) AS follows_type,
  message_type.date AS message_type_date,
  mentions.date AS mentions_date,
  follows.date AS follows_date
ORDER BY date
SKIP 0
LIMIT 25
```

But then I think you might get repeats of values depending on how you match.

Answer (score 0):

I want to steal yours / cybersam's solution with another suggestion.  I'm going to work off cybersam's.  Firstly, I'm thinking you don't want to only return results where there is always a path from `user-[:Owner]->(:Message)-:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(:User)`, so that needs to be an optional match.  But secondly, I *think* it will be faster if you only match the end user variable once.  Like so:

```
MATCH (me:User { username:'bob' }), (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:Owner]->(m:Message)<-[r:Likes|:Reply|:Share]-(user)
WITH me, collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:user, message:m, date:r.created_on }) AS a1
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[r:Mentions]-(m:Message)<-[:Owner]-(user)
WITH me, collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:user, message:m, date:r.created_on }) AS a2, a1
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)<-[r:Follows]-(user)
WITH collect({ type:lower(type(r)), user:user, date:r.created_on }) + a2 + a1 AS all
UNWIND all AS activity
RETURN activity
ORDER BY activity.date
LIMIT 25;
```